# ¿Cómo mostrar en un archivo Blade código HTML obtenido de una base de datos?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

Buen día:

Tengo el siguiente texto que guardo en la base de datos MySQL:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam
>   tincidunt lacus ac orci pretium, id commodo eros elementum. Mauris ac
>   tortor condimentum, sollicitudin risus quis, porttitor ligula. Nunc in
>   tellus ut leo ***consequat tristique. Nulla facilisi.*** Cras posuere vel
>   sapien a viverra. In fermentum malesuada ipsum, a cursus velit. Ut et
>   risus pharetra, mattis augue sit amet, blandit augue. Nullam interdum
>   dictum neque, sit amet laoreet turpis tincidunt ac. Mauris at tellus
>   id risus cursus tincidunt in quis lectus. Proin gravida nisi metus. Ut
>   rhoncus aliquet lacus.

Cómo le hago para que al momento de obtener ese registro de la base de datos en el documento de Blade cambie los asteriscos por llaves `<strong>consequat tristique. Nulla facilisi.</strong>` y me las haga negritas?

Pues cuando lo hago me aparecen las llaves.

Leí que utilizará `{!! $texto !!}` pero también menciona que no es recomendable, ¿habrá alguna forma diferente?

Comment: Lograste transformar los asteriscos a etiquetas? Cómo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo resolví, lo que hice fue instalar la siguiente dependencia de BBCode a través de Composer:

```
composer require genert/bbcode
```

Esta es la página en Github: https://github.com/Genert/bbcode

Así que lo siguiente fue quitar el auto escape `{{ $texto }}` y utilice el unescaped `{!! $texto !!}` para poder visualizar el código HTML del texto.

Así que metí el texto dentro de la clase BBCode que convierte la siguientes etiquetas `[b][i][u]` en `<b><i><u>` quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
{!! BBCode::convertToHtml($texto) !!}
```

Pero para no tener un ataque XSS, lo que hice fue meter todo eso dentro de la función `strip_tags` para permitir únicamente las etiquetas `<b><i><u>` quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
{!! strip_tags(BBCode::convertToHtml($texto),'<b><i><u>') !!}
```

Y listo!!!

Answer (score 0):

La forma más sencilla de mostrar HTML en la vista generada con ***blade*** es usando la función nativa de PHP: **htmlspecialchars()** delimitando la llamada de la forma adecuada:

Ejemplo:

```
{!! htmlspecialchars('Hola mundo.</b>') !!}
```

Mostrará:

```
Hola mundo.</b>
```